# Converting from list to string Python

Tags: python, python-idle

Right now, here is my code:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
nameList = list(name)
del nameList[1]
newName = str(nameList)
print"Your new name is: " + str(newName) + "."
```

When I use this code, the problem is that the last line prints the newName like a list, even though I have converted it to a string.

```
Your new name is: ['j', 'k', 'e'].
```

I want this new name to be displayed like normal text. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you converting it to a list in the first place with list()?

Comment: @monkut: To delete the second character, it seems.

Comment: A different way to accomplish this is to cut the string.  name = name[:1] + name[2:].  This cuts out the second character without having to go to a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to concatenate the elements of the list using the [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) string method:

```
>>> new_name = ['j', 'k', 'e']
>>> print ''.join(new_name)
jke
```

Alternatively, just don't convert the string to a list at all and use string operations to achieve what you want:

```
>>> name = 'jake'
>>> new_name = name[:1] + name[2:]
>>> print new_name
jke
```

Comment: To elaborate, calling `list(a_str)` is nearly always the wrong thing to do. (Guess I didn't elaborate much).

Comment: @Julian: I've seen it being used in the context of shellcode generation, where it's quite helpful (insert a piece of binary data at position X? No problem, just do `blob[X:len(part)] = part`). Of course we could do `blob = blob[:X] + part + blob[X+len(part)]`, but why make it more complicated then necessary?

Comment: That said, of course we should encourage beginners to make heavy use of immutability and the functional paradigm, so by all means, *in this situation, use strings!*

Comment: Shell code generation? Sounds nasty :P. In Python 2, for assembling bytes there's also `str.format`, unfortunately that's gone away in Python 3 for now. But certainly there can be exceptions yeah. I doubt that anyone that needs to ask whether they have a good reason is likely to have one of them though :). Otherwise, I've upvoted you for the correct answer :).

Comment: @Julian: This was just an example, of course you're right in most of the cases :P Thanks for the upvote

Answer (score 2):

I messed around with the code for a little bit. Try this:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
nameList = list(name)
del nameList[1]
test = ''.join(nameList)
print"Your new name is: " + test + "."
```

Hope it helps. (:

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import string
>>> v = string.ascii_uppercase[:20]
>>> v
 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'
>>> v = list(v)
>>> v[:10]
  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

>>> v1 = ''.join(v)
>>> v1
  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST'
```

Alternatively, i believe you can do what you want in a *single* line of code (once you have retrieved the user input and bound it to a variable) so after your first line:

```
print("name is {0}{1}".format(name[:1], name[2:]))
```

Comment: I think he wants to delete the second character, so it would be `name[:1] + name[2:]`